# How do you peek gcp pubsub messages?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pubsub topic that has subscription with a few unacked messages and I would like to peek at these messages. Is it possible?

The REST APIs doesnt seem to have a method that allows that. Should I setup another `PULL` subscription, and use the GCP web app to pull but not ack the messages (so they remain on the topic)?

Comment: Messages lived in a subscription, not in a topic. You can't ack anything on a topic. You must ask your messages or purge the queue, or wait for message expiration, or create a dead letter topic to publish theses messages elsewhere (and ack them in the current subscription)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thx. Edited question to reflect that. So is there no way to peek at a message to figure out which message is hanging around unacked?

Comment: I know 2 solutions: If it's a pull subscription, you can see the message in the queue. If it's a push subscription, you can only log the message in the target of the push, or add a dead letter topic to push them in another topic, create a pull subscription on it (BEFORE setting your dead letter topic, else you will lost your messages) and pull the messages as any pull subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to view unacknowledged messages in a subscription. However, there are a few workarounds that you can explore, aside from the Pull and Push method mentioned by [@guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere), consider [replaying](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview) the messages by [seeking a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview#:%7E:text=You%20can%20replay%20unacknowledged%20messages,to%20seek%20to%20a%20snapshot.).

> You can replay unacknowledged messages by using a snapshot to seek to any of the topic's subscriptions.
>
> Unlike with seeking to a time, you don't need to perform any special subscription configuration to seek to a snapshot. You just need to create the snapshot ahead of time.